# jQuery append clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am statically binding the accordion panel like this:

```
<body>
  <ul class="accordion_menu">
    <li class="has_sub">
      <div class="arrow_trigger up_arrow down_arrow"></div>
      <span>Dropdown</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=''>Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Option 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>     
</body>
```

The requirement was to bind the accordion using JSON/XML. The call to JSON Object/XML works fine, but when I append the static element using a jQuery accordion panel, it is not functional.

Partial code is given below:

```
$('.accordion_menu').append(
   "<li class='has_sub'>"
   + "<div class='arrow_trigger up_arrow down_arrow'>"
   + "</div><span>**JSON DATA GOES HERE**</span>"
   + "<ul>"
   + "<li><a href=''>Option 1</a></li>"
   + "<li><a href=''>Option 2</a></li>"
   + "</ul>"
   + "</li>");
```

What is the issue with the `.append()` function?

Comment: Your code should work as-is, once you fix the basic javascript syntax errors, though i don't see the *"accordion functionality"* you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the `.append()` function, but since the elements it adds were not present at the time the accordion was instantiated, they don't receive any of the event handlers with which the other accordion elements have been decorated. You'll want to either re-instantiate the accordion after the `.append()` call, or wait until after `.append()` to instantiate the accordion.

Comment: how to reinitiate it ,is there any reference link for this re initiate functionality?

Comment: @user2643269 It depends on which jQuery accordion plugin you're using. You may be able to reinstantiate it by calling the same function you called to create the accordion in the first place, or you may not; refer to the relevant documentation for details.